# What caused the earthquake in Kuwait on Nov 12, 2017?

Tags: earthquakes

What are the causes of [the earthquake in Kuwait](http://www.cnn.com/2017/11/12/middleeast/iraq-earthquake/index.html)  on Nov 12, 2017?

Comment: The USGS provides a good initial summary. https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us2000bmcg#executive

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research by the asker.